# If I fix and relaunch a broken Chrome extension that hasn't been updated for 2+ years, will it get removed from store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the source code (from github) for this extension. It has gone from 5 stars with hundreds of thousands of users to now 3 stars because it just doesn't work anymore. The developer hasn't updated it for 2+ years. I'm really interested in fixing and relaunching it.

Will it get removed from Chrome store for "violating copyright", breaking TOS, or something? I would like to call it "[OLD EXTENSION NAME] Revived" or "[OLD EXTENSION NAME] Relaunched" so users of the old extension know that it's been relaunched.

Comment: Off Topic due to being a Legal Question. Hopefully the extension contains a clear license — which dictates the ability to create a derived work — that makes it suitable to clone/fix/republish, and under what terms. It may also be possible to reach out or the original authors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is dealing with (general and unrefined) legality.

Comment: I would recommend that you fork the unmaintained plugin, and publish it as a "new" plugin (if the license allows it).